# Random line apperar in object modee

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, command-line, object-mode, origin

a line appear in object mode, but it doen´t appear in edit mode. how can i delete it??
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using any modifiers?

Comment: the only modifier i use is  brevel and then shade smooth

Comment: Bevel modifier is the cause, is the clamp option on? Did you try to merge by distance?

Comment: finally solve the problem, thanks you a lot